# How to send custom props to my custom searchPanel from devExtreme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devextreme

So i want to pass my custom onChange function to my custom plugin in ReactJS with devextreme grid.

I have my searchPanel override like this:

```
import { withComponents } from '@devexpress/dx-react-core';
import { SearchPanel as SearchPanelBase } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
import { SearchPanelInput as Input } from './SearchPanelInputBase';

export const SearchPanel = withComponents({ Input })(SearchPanelBase);
```

and then my searchPanelInputBase

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import { Switch } from '@material-ui/core';
import StoreUsers from '../store/StoreUsers';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.action.active,
  },
  flexSpaced: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '100%',
  }
});


let getActives = false

const SearchPanelInputBase = ({
  myCustomFunctionFromProps, classes, onValueChange, value, getMessage, props, ...restProps
}) => (
  <div className={classes.flexSpaced}>
    <Switch
      onChange={myCustomFunctionFromProps}
    />
    <Input
      onChange={e => onValueChange(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
      type="text"
      placeholder={getMessage('searchPlaceholder')}
      {...restProps}
      startAdornment={(
        <InputAdornment position="start">
          <Search />
        </InputAdornment>
    )}
      />
  </div>
);

SearchPanelInputBase.propTypes = {
  myCustomFunctionFromProps: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onValueChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  getMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
SearchPanelInputBase.defaultProps = {
  value: '',
};

export const SearchPanelInput = withStyles(styles)(SearchPanelInputBase);
```

Finally i call in where i want like this

```
      <SearchPanel
        inputComponent={props => (
          <SearchPanelInput myCustomFunctionFromProps={this.myCustomFunctionFromProps} {...props} />
        )}
      />
```

But this is not working, my prop types say the function is undefined, i suspect the props are not spreading correctly but i do not know how to override the other component

EDIT:

my function

```
  myCustomFunctionFromProps = () => console.log('lel')
```

Comment: Have you tried just receiving props and use `console.log` to figure out what exactly is getting passed through? Like this:
`const SearchPanelInputBase = (props) => {  console.log(props); };`

Comment: Yes, it just return the default element props like value, onValueChange,getMessage and classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withComponents` is not passing down your custom props.

It can be used with several components:

```
export const Table = withComponents({ Row, Cell })(TableBase);
```

And it just HOC for:

```
    <TableBase
      rowComponent={Row}
      cellComponent={Cell}
    />
```

So how should it know to which one custom props go?

You have to define another Input wrapper in scope with `myCustomFunctionFromProps` function.

```
  Input2 = props => (
    <SearchPanelInput myCustomFunctionFromProps={this.myCustomFunctionFromProps} {...props} />
  )
```

and use `SearchPanel` from `@devexpress/dx-react-grid`

```
    <SearchPanel
      inputComponent={this.Input2}
    />
```

also you should change:

```
onChange={() => myCustomFunctionFromProps}
myCustomFunctionFromProps={() => this.myCustomFunctionFromProps}
```

to:

```
onChange={myCustomFunctionFromProps}
myCustomFunctionFromProps={this.myCustomFunctionFromProps}
```

or (although it's renundant):

```
onChange={() => myCustomFunctionFromProps()}
myCustomFunctionFromProps={() => this.myCustomFunctionFromProps()}
```

Comment: Your answer made a lot of sense but my props and custom fucntion still return undefined when i log them. updated my question

Comment: and you import `SearchPanel` from `devexpress/dx-react-grid`?

Comment: Ops, i completly missed the import somehow! It's all working as intended now!